# focus is not working in Mozila firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, focus

I am trying to validate date using jquery. If user entered invalid date, then it should set focus in same control. I have written below code it works fine in all browsers but in Mozilla its not working.

#### JavaScript Code:

```
function CheckDate(txt) {
    var isValid = false;
    var txtDate = $('input[id$=' + txt + ']').val();
    if (txtDate.length == 0) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else {
        if (isDate(txtDate)) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        else {
            isValid = false;
            $('#' + txt).focus();
        }
    }
    
    //alert(txtControl);
}
```

I am calling this function on onBlur event of textbox.
I didnt got any solution for this. If anybody knows than please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.trigger('focus')` instead of simple `.focus()`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I feel that the selector has issues. We need to see the value of `txt`. So can you change your this part of code:

```
$('#' + txt).focus();
```

To:

```
$('input[id$=' + txt + ']').focus();
```

Comment: Can you share the calling function? The `CheckDate(txt)` with the value of `txt`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$('#' + txt).attr('value');
```

and use this

```
$('#' + txt).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

it works with focus inside setTimeOut : http://www.echoknowledge.com/javascript-focus-is-not-working-in-firefox/